# Google spreadsheet delete row based on value 0

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have looked at this discussion but didn't want to hijack it.  [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11058019/delete-a-row-in-google-spreadsheet-base-on-value-of-cell-in-row)

I'm a newbie to google scripts but i have found this one which work in some way

```
function deleteRows() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = ss.getSheetByName('ark1'); // 0AmWS-4fnAa_OdG9aV210NnZlZHlDYVRZSUxrOFdwX1E&usp
  var values = s.getDataRange().getValues();

  var deleted = 0;  // Counter (don't need if we loop backwards)
  for (var row = 0; row < values.length; row++) {
    if (values[row][2] == '' || values[row][2] == 0) {
      s.deleteRow(row + 1 - deleted);
      deleted++;
    }
  }
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
};
```

It works in my test spreadsheet. But only in the column C. When i enter the number 0 the row is deleted. I would like it to react to a different column. ie N instead.
How do I do that?
I bet the answer is pretty obvious, but I just can't figure it out.
Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks!

Jesper Homann

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Columns begin with A = 1, B = 2, C = 3 etc... so column N is 14 .

### BUT

Arrays count from 0 so in your code example you will have to use

```
if (values[row][13] == '' || values[row][13] == 0) {
```

I hope I make it clear enough.

Note that in the code above you used `s.deleteRow(row + 1 - deleted);` and the `+1` comes for the very same reason : rows count from 1 and arrays count from 0 .

IMO, the variable name `row` was definitely not a good choice since it's ambiguous wether it's a sheet row or an array row... one should call it n or i, anything neutral. In this example it's an array row thus starting from 0 then +1 to get the sheet row (the one we delete).

Comment: Thanks very much. It certainly helped me out here. clear and fast reply. Like it very much!!

Comment: Hi again. Unfortuneately the scripts also deletes the rows i have above where i have the value 0. Is there any way to work around this? I would like it to only delete the rows with the value 0. Thanks again!

Comment: Is the script in your question an exact copy of the one you use ?

Comment: then it should not delete anything other than rows that satify the condition. Try placing a Logger.log(row + 1 - deleted) in the loop and view the log to see what actually happens.